# Exercise about proper maps from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Given these two maps, I have to find out whether they are proper or not:$$f_1:(x\quad y)^t\rightarrow(x+y^2\quad x^2+y)^t$$ $$f_2:(x\quad y)^t\rightarrow(\frac{x^2} {x^2+y^2+1}\quad \frac{y} {x^2+y^2+1})^t$$

1) Moving to polar coordinates, I reasoned like this: $\rho cos\theta+\rho^2sin^2\theta\le a$ together with $\rho^2cos^2\theta+\rho sin \theta\le b$ implies that $\rho^2 +\rho(cos\theta+sin\theta)-(a+b)\le0$, whence $\rho(cos\theta+sin\theta)-(a+b)\le0$. So we can say that $\rho\le|\frac {a+b} {cos\theta+sin\theta}|\le|a+b|$.

2) Again with polar coordinates, we have $\rho^2cos^2\theta\le a(1+\rho^2)$, so $\rho^2\le \frac a {cos^2\theta-a}\le a$ since $a\le1$. Clearly it follows that $\rho$ is smaller than a finite value.

So I demonstrated that if $K\subset\Bbb R^2$ is bounded, $f_i^{-1}(K)$ is bounded too; since both these functions are continuous, the preimage of a closed set is a closed set and consequently they are proper. First off I'd like to know if what I've done is fully correct, because I'm not very sure, and then I'd like to know if there is some better method to solve this exercise. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for $f_1$ does not work as it is. You may have $\cos \theta + \sin \theta = 0$, e.g. for $\theta = 3\pi/2$. However, it can easily be corrected. Let us work with polar coordinates as you suggested, i.e. write $(x,y) = r(cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. Let $B \subset \mathbb R^2$ be bounded. Choose $a > 0$ such that $B \subset [-a,a]^2$ and let $f_1(r(cos \theta, \sin \theta)) = (r \cos \theta + r^2 \cos^2 \theta, r^2 \sin \theta + r \sin \theta) \in B \subset  [-a,a]^2$. This implies
$$r^2 - 2r \le r^2 + r(cos \theta + \sin \theta) \le 2a .$$
Now the equation $r^2 -2r -2a = 0$ has the two roots $r_{1/2} = 1 \pm \sqrt{1 +2a}$. Hence $r^2 - 2r \le 2a$ implies $1 - \sqrt{1 +2a} \le r \le 1 + \sqrt{1 +2a}$. This shows that $f_1^{-1}(B)$ is bounded.

$f_2$ is not proper. Let $C = [0,1] \times \{ 0 \}$ which is compact. You have $f_2^{-1}(C) = \mathbb R \times \{ 0 \}$ which is not compact.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually to demonstrate that $f_1$ is proper one coul say that $x+y^2\le a\Rightarrow x\le a$ and similarly $y\le b$; then $x+y^2\ge c\Rightarrow x\ge c-b^2$ and so $ y\ge d-a^2$ right?

Comment: You may take $a = b$. But what are $c$ and $d$?